# Matplotlib - how to rescale pixel intensities for RGB image

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib

I am confused regarding how matplotlib handles fp32 pixel intensities. To my understanding, it rescales the values between max and min values of the image. However, when I try to view images originally in [0,1] by rescaling their pixel intensites to [-1,1] (by im*2-1) using imshow(), the image appears differently colored. How do I rescale so that images don't differ ?

EDIT : Please look at the image - [image]

PS: I need to do this as part of a program that outputs those values in [-1,1]

Following is the code used for this:

```
img = np.float32(misc.face(gray=False))
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
img = img/255 # Convert to 0,1 range
print (np.max(img), np.min(img))    
img0 = ax[0].imshow(img)
plt.colorbar(img0,ax=ax[0])
print (np.max(2*img-1), np.min(2*img-1))
img1 = ax[1].imshow(2*img-1)  # Convert to -1,1 range
plt.colorbar(img1,ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

The max,min output is :

```
(1.0, 0.0)
(1.0, -1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using matplotlib wrong here.

The normalization-step should work correctly, if it's active. **The [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) tell us, that is only active by default, if the input-image is of type float!**

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)

# This usage shows different colors because there is no normalization
# FIRST ROW
f = misc.face(gray=True)
print(f.dtype)
g = f*2  # just some operation to show the difference between usages
ax[0,0].imshow(f)
ax[0,1].imshow(g)

# This usage makes sure that the input-image is of type float
# -> automatic normalization is used!
# SECOND ROW
f = np.asarray(misc.face(gray=True), dtype=float)  # TYPE!
print(f.dtype)
g = f*2  # just some operation to show the difference between usages
ax[1,0].imshow(f)
ax[1,1].imshow(g)

plt.show()
```

#### Output

```
uint8
float64
```

[image]

#### Analysis

The first row shows the wrong usage, because the input is of type int and therefore no normalization will be used.

The second row shows the correct usage!

EDIT:

sascha has correctly pointed out in the comments that rescaling is not applied for RGB images and inputs must be ensured to be in [0,1] range.

Comment: I have added an image to clarify. I'm using float - the problem is that I want to move from [0,1] to [-1,1] without changing the image displayed.

Comment: @Jagadeesh Then show the code and also some debug-outputs regarding shape, type, minmax of the arrays. Normilization is working correctly for me. It seems there is something else the matter with your code. It seems to be related to the usage of colored-images (instead of grayscale with my example).

Comment: @Jagadeesh You could also explain a bit more what's the problem in your pipeline. Which kind of images with which format are to be used in the final plot? A mixture of -1,1 and 0,1? Only images of -1,1? And of course there is the question if you would need global normalization, when plotting two different images, both within -1,1; but min/max differ. Maybe the preprocessing needs to be outsourced then. It all depends on your task! This could be nicely done through scikit-learn OR (which i recommend): build everything on top of scikit-image which should keep coherent reprs. internally.

Comment: I agree the discrepancy is due to using RGB images. In my experiment I have RGB images in 0-1 range floats. However, after applying some transformations (eventually a tanh function) the resulting images are in [-1,1] range. My problem is that an image whose pixel values are stretched from [0,1] to [-1,1] does not appear the same in matplotlib which implies the normalization is not happening properly. All my images are [-1,1] and there is no mixing and they appear weird but when I transform them to [0,1] they appear fine.

Comment: @Jagadeesh The [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) say, that the input of ```plt.imshow``` has to be in range(0,1) and there is no normalization of images with colors (only gray-scale is normalized). **This means, that preprocessing your images to (0,1) is your job before calling imshow**. I don't see any problem here to add this to your pipeline (even if there are some decisions to make regarding normalization; local vs. global... i would use sklearns MinMaxScaler)!